# Nested Serializer Fields Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two models (User and Province) and serializers. The user creates a province and in the province model I have the user id. The challenge is when creating nested serializers, I only want the first_name and last_name from the user but is is giving me everything including the password. Below are the serializers

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']


class ProvinceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Province
        fields = ['id', 'province_uid', 'province_name', 'date_created','created_by','user' ]
        read_only_fields = ('id','province_uid', 'date_created')
        depth = 1
```

**Edit**
Below is the response and I would like to only have the first_name and last_name from the user.

```
      "id": 1,
      "province_uid": "9c74aeda-0734-465f-847b-0fa89ca7ea21",
      "province_name": "Lusaka",
      "date_created": "2021-07-12T06:42:22.973441+02:00",
      "created_by": {
        "id": 1,
        "password": "db_password",
        "user_uid": "3d0f353c-260a-41b7-a535-3ea5a20fe8a5",
        "username": "admin",
        "email": "isaachatilima@gmail.com",
        "cell": "260966477311",
        "first_name": "Global",
        "last_name": "Admin"}
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove `depth=1`? I assume it overrides your `fields=[....,'user']`

Comment: Hi Klim, if I remove depth=1 then I wont get the name of the user who created the record, it will only show the created_by : 1. I would want to get the names only if that's something possible

Comment: Another approach is in `ProvinceSerializer`, change `user` to `created_by`

Comment: This actually helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it a little more and you should adjuste the code a little bit and
you don´t need a `UserSerializer` for that case in `ProvinceSerializer`.

I don´t know your model but where did you get `created_by`-field? Is it a part of your model? If not it won´t work to change `user` to `created_by` as mentioned.

##### model

```
class Province(models.Model):
    province_uid = models.UUIDField()
    province_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

##### serializer

```
class ProvinceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    created_by = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Province
        exclude = ['user']
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'province_uid', 'date_created')

    def get_created_by(self, obj):
        return {'first_name': obj.user.first_name, 'last_name': obj.user.last_name}
```

##### view

```
class TestView(views.APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        serializer = ProvinceSerializer(Province.objects.all(), many=True)
        return Response(data=serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Mark the password field as write only.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']
        extra_kwargs = {
                'password': {'write_only': True, 'required': False}
        }
```

Update:

You need to serialize `created_by` by providing `UserSerializer` else the `depth=1` will populate all the data from foreign key relation.

Also not sure why you need `many=True` for `user` attribute in the `ProvinceSerializer`. Can only comment on it after seeing the `models`

```
class ProvinceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    created_by = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Province
        fields = ['id', 'province_uid', 'province_name', 'date_created','created_by','user' ]
        read_only_fields = ('id','province_uid', 'date_created')
        depth = 1
```

Comment: Hi MjZac, sorry maybe my english is not that good. From the UserSerializer I am only using/needing it when displaying the provinces and I want to see who created it. I have noticed that even if I remove fields from the UserSerializer I still get all the model fields. I have edited the post kindly check and advise.

Comment: @IsaacHatilima I have updated my answer ( and your English looks good to me :) )

Answer (score 0):

Both the answers did exactly what I needed thank you so much Klim and MjZac, wish I could get you coffee. To anyone with a similar challenge, just pick any of the two and it will work. To answer Klims question, created_by is a foreign key of the User model. I have it as;

```
created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="Created By", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
```

in the Province model. Below are the serializers with one commented after testing solution:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name')
        read_only_fields = ('first_name', 'last_name')

# class ProvinceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
#     created_by = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
#     class Meta:
#         model = Province
#         fields = ['id', 'province_uid', 'province_name', 'date_created','created_by' ]
#         read_only_fields = ('id','province_uid', 'date_created','created_by')
#         depth = 1

class ProvinceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    created_by = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Province
        fields = ['id', 'province_uid', 'province_name', 'date_created','created_by' ]
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'province_uid', 'date_created')

    def get_created_by(self, obj):
        return {'first_name': obj.created_by.first_name, 'last_name': obj.created_by.last_name}
```

Notice I added read_only_fields on the UserSerializer because they required input on my Swagger UI, right now I am getting "created_by": {} on Swagger but I can live with that as I find ways of removing it completely.
Happy coding and do stay safe.